# Count distinct values for 1st 'group by' field while are two of them

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a list of documents created by user, with date, number of week, some description field. What I need is to calculate how many documents was created every week and how many users participated. Using query like this below I can calculate easily number of docs created, unfortunately, count of distinct users is multiplied as single user may create documents in different categories. So some users are counted many times.

```
sel  WEEK
, DESCRIPTION 
, count(*) as DOC_CNT
,count(distinct USER_ID) as USER_CNT
from THE_TABLE_1
group by 1,2;
```

I would like to count distinct users in each week, regardless of DESCRIPTION field. Do you know any elegant way to obtain this?
I am using Teradata engine, if it would matter.

Thanks

EDIT: 
Input looks like that:

```
    DOC_NO  USER_ID DT  WEEK    day_of_week DESCRIPTION
1   0019071988  AC_N490314  10/03/2020  10  3   Maintain Business Partner
2   0018864387  AC_SSELVAM1 03/03/2020  9   3   Customer Change
3   0018840898  AC_RHARIHAR1    02/03/2020  9   2   Change Asset
4   0018883336  AC_AGNANA1  03/03/2020  9   3   Create Asset
5   0017743110  AC_DKUPPUSA1    03/02/2020  5   2   Change Bank
6   0017946108  AC_SMADHESH 07/02/2020  5   6   Create Supplier
7   0019573163  AC_SJAYACHA1    26/03/2020  12  5   Select Idocs
8   0017660339  AC_SSELVAM1 31/01/2020  4   6   Create material
9   0018324802  AC_DKUPPUSA1    18/02/2020  7   3   VIM Workplace
10  0019161678  AC_N478361  14/03/2020  10  7   Release Blocked Invoices
```

and output should be like below, though USER_CNT values miscalculated here.

```
    WEEK    DESCRIPTION DOC_CNT USER_CNT
1   10  Reset Cleared Items 229 13
2   3   Maintain Business Partner   600 10
3   4   Data Capture/Indexing Invoice   4,974   31
4   7   Other   1,207   54
5   9   Check VIM Business Rules    2,132   23
6   6   Check VIM Business Rules    2,863   29
7   5   Other   1,096   52
8   12  Check VIM Business Rules    1,390   19
9   4   Check VIM Business Rules    2,710   27
10  4   Other   1,462   56
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is a bit odd.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: jahr: Teradata, as I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're grouping the rows using the `description` field in your current query:

```
COUNT(*) AS doc_cnt, -- # rows per week / description
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_cnt -- # distinct users per week / description
```

From what I understand, you want `# documents and distinct users per week, regardless of description`.  Assuming it's one row per document, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  src.week, 
  MAX(src.docs_per_week) AS docs_per_week, 
  COUNT(*) AS users_per_week
FROM (
  SELECT 
    week, 
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY week) AS docs_per_week -- # rows per week
  FROM the_table_1
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY week, user_id) = 1 -- Remove duplicate users
) src
GROUP BY src.week -- One row per week
```

Comment: Thanks Ravioli. I have modyfied Qualify, adding QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY week, user_id order by doc_no) and it works perfect.